# Python 3 name tuple position

Tags: python-3.x, tuples

If I have the coordinate tuple `(10.1, 15.2)`, how can I make it so that I can call `10.1` as simply `x` instead of `coordinates[0]`, and `y` instead of `coordinates[1]`?

I want to do this so that I can pass a tuple from function to function while still being able to call `x` and `y` easily. I could just:

```
x = coordinates[0]
y = coordinated[1]
```

but that seems like a bad idea -- lengthy and I'd have to repeat it for each function.

Comment: Use a [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)?

Comment: [Don't forget to Google!](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+3+name+tuple+position) The answer is the first search result for your question's title.

Comment: @user2357112 To be fair, that's due to autocorrect. You're right, though.

Comment: @jonrsharpe So, for this example, I would do `collections.namedtuple(coordinates, ['x', 'y']) = ???`

Comment: Give it a try and find out!

Comment: @jonrsharpe That wasn't an actual example, more of a, "So how would I do this for this example"?

Comment: So read the docs I linked and figure it out, this isn't a terribly complicated problem

Comment: @jonrsharpe Reading ATM, just thought I'd also ask if it were to end up being faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
   > from collections import namedtuple
   > c = namedtuple('Coords',['x','y'])
   > xy = c(5,6)
   > xy
   => Coords(x=5, y=6)
   > xy.x
   => 5
   > xy.y
   => 6
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, really helped me understand. Will mark as answer ASAP.